# Java program cannot find com.mongodb.Block

Tags: java, mongodb

I am working on a Java program with Mongodb.  The following 2 jar files are placed in CLASSPATH: mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar, bson-3.0.2.jar.
When compiling the Java program, I saw the error:
error: cannot find symbol
import com.mongodb.Block;
Taking a look into mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar, com.mongodb.Block was not there. 
Did I miss something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need `mongodb-driver-core` jar.

It doesn't seem you are using a dependency management tool (Gradle,Maven) to handle your dependencies, otherwise it would have taken care to download `mongodb-driver-core` (required by `mongodb-driver`).

Also you should align your dependencies versions: promote`bson` to version `3.2.2` as well (again dependency management system would have taken care for it).

Alternatively, you can use `mongo-java-driver` jar instead of the other three (
`bson`, `mongodb-driver-core` and `mongodb-driver`)

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky using MongoDB with Java, but a project management tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) makes library imports very easy. This is the import for Mongo (you should probably check the version number).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I suggest checking it out.